# How to write assertTimeoutPreemptively (JUnit 5) in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

Till now I was working on JUnit 5 and now I have to work on an old system with JUnit 4 and I cannot update JUnit 5 there. I have a test in JUnit 5 that I have to write in JUnit 4 but I am not sure how it will work or how to write? Below is the JUnit 5 version of the test.

```
@AfterEach
void afterEach() throws Exception {
    // Bleed off any events that were generated...
    assertTimeoutPreemptively(ofMillis(MESSAGE_CLEARING_TIMEOUT_MS), () -> {
        boolean tryAgain = true;
        while (tryAgain) {
            try {
                final IMessageFacade message = messageConsumer.receiveMessage(MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS);
                message.acknowledge();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                tryAgain = false;
            }
        }
    });
    broker.stop();
}
```

In the test, I am using `assertTimeoutPreemptively()` and am not sure how to convert it to JUnit 4. I tried putting a timeout which is a global timeout in JUnit 4 but that didn't work. Any guidance in terms of writing above `@AfterEach` condition with JUnit 4?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't assertions run only once? Finding asserts in test teardown is somehow surprising. Consider to make your assertions part of your tests.

In JUnit 5 this looks like:

```java
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;

public class TimeoutJUnit5Test {

    @Test @Timeout(value = 10, unit = MILLISECONDS)
    void junitFiveTimeout() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and in JUnit 4:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeoutJUnit4Test {

    @Test(timeout = 10)
    public void junitFourTimeout() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What's stopping you from using both versions of JUnit? (pom.xml):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Last option would be to simply copy / adapt the behaviour from the new JUnit 5 [assertTimeoutPreemptively()](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/5e41ebe612fd67e905f96f1dd3184a071b65be17/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/AssertTimeout.java#L124) to you own project.